# Pandas group by and sum two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Beginner question. This seems like it should be a straightforward operation, but I can't figure it out from reading the docs.

I have a df with this structure:

```
|integer_id|int_field_1|int_field_2|
```

The integer_id column is non-unique, so I'd like to group the df by integer_id and sum the two fields.

The equivalent SQL is:

```
SELECT integer_id, SUM(int_field_1), SUM(int_field_2) FROM tbl
GROUP BY integer_id
```

Any suggestions on the simplest way to do this?

EDIT: Including input/output

```
Input:  
integer_id  int_field_1 int_field_2   
2656        36          36  
2656        36          36  
9702        2           2  
9702        1           1
```

Ouput using df.groupby('integer_id').sum():

```
integer_id  int_field_1 int_field_2  
2656        72          72  
9702        3           3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to call `sum` on a `groupby` object:

```
df.groupby('integer_id').sum()
```

See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby) for further examples

Comment: Just to add to this a bit, since my situation was slightly more complicated: if you want to group by mutiple fields the only difference is `df.groupby(['field1', 'field2']).sum()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it

```
data.groupby(by=['account_ID'])['purchases'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the .agg() function; provides the ability to (1) persist type DataFrame, (2) apply averages, counts, summations, etc. and (3) enables groupby on multiple columns while maintaining legibility.

```
df.groupby(['att1', 'att2']).agg({'att1': "count", 'att3': "sum",'att4': 'mean'})
```

using your values...

```
df.groupby(['integer_id']).agg({'int_field_1': "sum", 'int_field_2': "sum" })
```