# pandas group dates to quarterly and sum sales column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I am learning python and at the moment I am playing with some sales data. The data is in csv format and is showing weekly sales.
I have below columns with some sample data as below:

```
store#  dept#    dates      weeklysales
   1      1    01/01/2005      50000
   1      1    08/01/2005      120000
   1      1    15/01/2005      75000
   1      1    22/01/2005      25000
   1      1    29/01/2005      18000 
   1      2    01/01/2005      15000
   1      2    08/01/2005      12000
   1      2    15/01/2005      75000
   1      2    22/01/2005      35000
   1      2    29/01/2005      28000
   1      1    01/02/2005      50000
   1      1    08/02/2005      120000
   1      1    15/02/2005      75000
   1      1    22/03/2005      25000
   1      1    29/03/2005      18000
```

I want to add the weeklysales to monthly basis in each department and want to display the records.

I have tried to use groupby function in Pandas from below links:

[how to convert monthly data to quarterly in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497199/how-to-convert-monthly-data-to-quarterly-in-pandas)

[Pandas group by and sum two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536032/pandas-group-by-and-sum-two-columns)

[Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

But what is happening in the above that I get sum of all the columns and getting the following output by adding the store and dept numbers as well:

```
store#  dept#    dates      weeklysales
   4      3     01/2005        28800
   4      1     01/2005        165000
   4      3     02/2005        245000
   4      3     03/2005        43000
```

I do not want to add store and dept numbers but want to just add the weeklysales figure by each month and want the display like:

```
store#  dept#    dates      weeklysales
   1      1     01/2005        28800
   1      2     01/2005        165000
   1      1     02/2005        245000
   1      1     03/2005        43000
```

Will be grateful if I can get a solution for that.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

Convert dates to month/year format and then group and sum sales.

```
(df.assign(dates=df.dates.dt.strftime('%m/%Y'))
    .groupby(['store#','dept#','dates'])
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
)
Out[243]: 
   store#  dept#    dates  weeklysales
0       1      1  01/2005       288000
1       1      1  02/2005       245000
2       1      1  03/2005        43000
3       1      2  01/2005       165000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Allen. This is what I wanted to achieve