# I am not abe to make accurate pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have one dataframe which contain many columns and i am trying to make pivot table 
like this

Data sample

```
program | InWappTable | InLeadExportTrack

VIC    |  True  | 1

VIC    | True   |1

VIC | True  |1

VIC | True  | 1
```

Here is my code

```
rec.groupby(['InWappTable', 'InLeadExportTrack','program']).size()
```

And Expected Output is

[image]

Comment: can you provide a data sample and expected output please.

Comment: I have provided sample and expected output

Comment: it is advisable to paste the data as text, not images as we would not be able to copy the image. also your expected output has some rows which your input doesnot

Comment: Actually i have big data set which contain many columns and thousands of rows thats why i m not able to share whole rows

Comment: how `df.groupby(['program'])['InWappTable','InLeadExporttrack'].count().reset_index()` work?

Comment: df.groupby(['program'])['InWappTable','InLeadExporttrack'].count().reset_index() missing the total value counts

Comment: how about `df.pivot_table(index='program', values=['InWappTable', 'InLeadExporttrack'], aggfunc='count', margins=True, margins_name='Total')`?

Comment: @JacopoRepossi this is giving me incoorect total

Comment: @MalikAsad incorrect compared to what expected result? I put 'count' as argument of `aggfunc` but could have been 'sum' or unique count..

Comment: @anky_91 thanks for your time and your solution is correct but missing total that i calculated with this t_wapp=df['InWappTable'].sum()

Comment: @JacopoRepossi I don't know why but aggfunc is not giving correct total rest of the value are same as groupby function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try this:

```
df_new=df.groupby(['program'])['InWappTable','InLeadExporttrack'].count().reset_index()
total = df_new.sum()
total['program'] = 'Total'
df_new=df_new.append(total, ignore_index=True)
print(df_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that you require a `pivot_table` here, though a `pivot_table` approach with `aggfunc` can also be used effectively.

Here is how I approached this

Generate some data

```
a = [['program','InWappTable','InLeadExportTrack'],
     ['VIC',True,1],
     ['Mall',False,15],
     ['VIC',True,101],
     ['VIC',True,1],
     ['Mall',True,74],
     ['Mall',True,11],
     ['VIC',False,44]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0])
print(df)

  program  InWappTable  InLeadExportTrack
0     VIC         True                  1
1    Mall        False                 15
2     VIC         True                101
3     VIC         True                  1
4    Mall         True                 74
5    Mall         True                 11
6     VIC        False                 44
```

First do `GROUP BY` with `count` aggregation

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['program']).count()
print(df_grouped)

         InWappTable  InLeadExportTrack
program                                
Mall               3                  3
VIC                4                  4
```

Then to get the [`sum` of all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536576/4057186)

```
num_cols = ['InWappTable','InLeadExportTrack']
df_grouped[num_cols] = df_grouped[num_cols].astype(int)
df_grouped.loc['Total']= df_grouped.sum(axis=0)
df_grouped.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
print(df_grouped)

  program  InWappTable  InLeadExportTrack
0    Mall            3                  3
1     VIC            4                  4
2   Total            7                  7
```

**EDIT**

Based on the comments in the OP, `df_grouped = df.groupby(['program']).count()` could be replaced by `df_grouped = df.groupby(['program']).sum()`. In this case, the output is shown below

```
  program  InWappTable  InLeadExportTrack
0    Mall            2                100
1     VIC            3                147
2   Total            5                247
```

Comment: why not `df.pivot_table(index='program', values=['InWappTable', 'InLeadExporttrack'], aggfunc='count', margins=True, margins_name='Total')`, which is a one line command? Am I missing something?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach! I'll fix my wording. For me, just looking at the raw data from the OP, it seemed like `groupby` was more intuitive. Using the sample data I posted, I get the same answer using your approach as what I posted. :)

Comment: oh great! I thought I was missing something, also because in the comments above he says that `aggfunc` is not giving him the right total...